# neighbour monopolising our cat

Tags: cats, legal

(I wasn't sure if pets, legal or German SE best, so apologies if this is the wrong site. Just let me know if one of the others a better place. Thanks.)

We live on a small housing estate in Munich, Germany, with our cat, who has a GPS collar.  We have a cat-flap and so he is free to come and go as he wants. Typically he sleeps indoors during the day in the winter, sleeps outdoors for most of the day when it's warmer, and pretty much all year he wanders around at evenings and nights, often covering a couple of kilometres. He visits many neighbours, staying perhaps half an hour here, an hour there. This is great: our community enjoys him, particularly the many children; we like to see him out and about; the cat gets a level of stimulation that we, on our own, could not provide. In short: everybody benefits.

However, several months ago, one particular neighbouring household started keeping our cat indoors. If we ask for our cat at the neighbour's front door then they say he's not there but immediately put him out of the back door (with one of us at the front and one at the back we can verify this happens). Sometimes they say he's not there. But a few seconds after such a visit, the GPS resumes sending us his location, which is close to the neighbours'. Sometimes we send a "beep" to the GPS, which the neighbours hear and put him out. Most often they let him back in just a few minutes later. Beeping them in this way is prefential: we do not want to be accused by the neighbour of harassement.

On one occasion the neighbours put sticky tape over the beeper. While the cat is a little disturbed by the noise, we felt sure the neighbours did this in order that they themselves could ignore the audio cue to return our cat. It took a while until we realised that they had done this, during which time it was harder to track down our cat at feeding time. Of course we cannot prove this, but the GPS track stopped and resumed at the neighbours'; the tape was not on the GPS before I beeped it while the cat was at the neighbours' and it was on the GPS after the cat had been at the neighbours'.

This morning we saw a new development: the GPS indicated the cat had been in their house for 11 hours overnight. I rang the neighbours' doorbell to get our cat, they did not answer, I returned home (about 30 metres away). Very briefly the GPS indicated that the cat had been put outside, but he would not come when whistled for food, which he usually did. A minute later GPS indicated the cat was back in their house and has remained there for another 7 hours until now.

We are reasonably sure that these neighbours are not feeding him proper food, but suspect they are giving him milk or treats in order to reinforce the behaviour they want: namely that he voluntarily spends all his time with them.

We have explained to the neighbours the upset and stress they are causing but they have explicitly said they will not change their behaviour.

Holiday season is approaching and it is easy to imagine we might actually miss flights because the neighbours' behaviour prevents us from dropping the cat off at the cattery/Katzenpension in a timely manner.

In desperation we have consulted the local police, who have given differing responses on two occassions: (1) they will only get involved if they neighbour refuses to surrender the cat on demand, (2) this is a matter for neighbours to resolve, not for the police. (If I beep the GPS, ring their doorbell and get no reaction is that refusing the surrender the cat?)

We could make the cat an indoor cat, but both we and the cat would not want that. We have discussed giving the cat away, which would be a permanent solution to the stress this is causing, but we can't bear to actually put that into effect. We have tried to care less about our cat (emotionally, I mean, not in relation to the cat's welfare) in order in order to protect ourselves from the upset and stress this is causing. But the sheer unfairness of the neighbours getting away with this behaviour is very difficult to swallow.

In case it is relevant: we have insurance for legal costs.

Does anybody have any advice please?

Comment: IANAL, but in Germany a cat is considered property, and even barn cats generally exceed in value what is considered a petty amount, more so if it is a specific breed. I would argue that the police are in the wrong here, they would have to be involved given the neighbour is withholding your property of considerable value. That said, they are probably right in not getting involved right away, this would likely just escalate things and nobody wants an all-out war with their neighbours. Maybe seeking legal advice, potentially a mediator might be the correct course of action here?

Comment: (German.SE would not fit, it is for language questions only)

Comment: this question might be a better fit over at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ as they have a number postings about how to handle nighbour problems.an other site where this question might fit is over at https://law.stackexchange.com/ if you want your question migrated you can ask one of the moderators here for help to do so.

Comment: I agree that this question seems more to focus on inter-human behaviour. Train the cat would not help in this case. --- Did you ask the neighbours about reasons, why they take the cat? What did they say? (I imagine an old granny, who says "The world outside is too risky for a cat, I save it from non-caring owners"... not my own opinion, but a possibility)

Comment: The neighbours say the cat is not there and yet the cat appears on the GPS mere seconds after we ask the neighbours. This has happened enough times to rule out coincidence. As described above, on one occassion my wife asked at the front of the house and I viewed the back of the house. My wife got the message "cat not here" and seconds later I saw them putting the cat out of the back door.

Comment: The neighbors may not be _aware_ the cat is there until you ask. In which case you need to take it up with the cat. Maybe work with the neighbors rather than against them,  to try to figure out what's attracting the cat and provide that at home. Realistically, though, unless you have evidence that they are actively restraining the cat, it's hard to argue that an outdoor cat isn't implicitly authorized to go wherever it wants to, or that being people the cat likes to visit constitutes abuse. A lawsuit for "alienation of feline affection" doesn't seem likely to be taken seriously.

Comment: i wonder if the gps of your cat can be plotted on a map,if it can you will have very strong indications about the location of your cat.or you can get a tiny camera you can put on your cat to see where he has been,most people will not like to be filmed in their own home so this has some legal aspects.